# writing subscripts in .plist files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string, plist

I am trying to represent the number 2 as a subscript in a property list file. I tried using`<sub>2</sub>`, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this? and will it be stored correctly in a string after I store it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plist file is typically a UTF-8 encoded XML file. You should be able to use the [Unicode subscript characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) as it is. To copy a non-ASCII char, you can use the Keyboard & Character Viewer (on Lion: System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources > Select the Keyboard & Character Viewer as an input source).

Answer (score 1):

A plist file is XML that follows a certain schema. `<sub>` is not a valid tag in that schema. If you want to put that kind of stuff in the PList, you have to put in into CDATA:

```
<![CDATA[<sub>2</sub>]]>
```